# @angular/schematics: Typescript failing to compile

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-schematics

I am trying to create a custom schematics.

I have created a template file which is to be generated by schematics.

This should create file with classname specified by inputs at command.

```
 export class <%= classify(name) %> {

}
```

But when I run using "npm run build", it throws error

```
    export class <%= classify(name) %> { 
               error TS1109: Expression expected.
```

I understand this is typescript error, But I am using `"typescript": "~3.1.6"` which should compile this.

I might be missing something basic. This is my first attempt with @angular/schematics.

Comment: When I see this it's almost always because there's a syntax error and/or the function doesn't return a value when it should (often because of said syntax error). I suspect your logic is broken somewhere that we can't see here.

Comment: Code which I have shown is the only content in ts file, also even without running I get underlined in red over the syntax after "export class"

Comment: Maybe it's not possible to dynamically create a classname this way? I haven't used that kind of template markup in a long time, did you get this from an example we could see? I also assume you have the latest schematics SDK installed? (The latest TS probably matches up with the latest SDK).

Comment: The code your displaying looks like a static asset (with templating options) included in your schematic, e.g., `files/class.ts`. I believe in order to execute the templating pattern, you need to pass a configuration object that includes the specified value, in this case **name**. Can you share the schematic code sample that calls your static asset with templating? I think I can help you out once I see a more complete sample.